# How to delete a detached tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I detached myself from a tmux session:

```
$ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Thu Aug 22 22:52:17 2013) [218x59]
```

Is there anyway I can simply delete it now that I am detached from it?

Comment: Related: If you're still attached to a tmux session, you can hit C-d (control + D) to detach from it and delete it in one fell swoop.  (Assuming you're at your shell prompt.)

Answer (score 74):

You want to use `tmux kill-session`:

```
<~> $ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Sat Aug 17 00:03:56 2013) [80x23]
2: 1 windows (created Sat Aug 24 16:47:58 2013) [120x34]

<~> $ tmux kill-session -t 2

<~> $ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Sat Aug 17 00:03:56 2013) [80x23]
```

Comment: Note that with `tmux kill-session -a -t $session` you can kill all sessions except the one specified. Details from the man page:

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#CLIENTS_AND_SESSIONS

Comment: `tmux kill-session -t` also works with session names

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete *all* the detached sessions you can use the following code:

```
tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_attached} #{session_id}' | \
  awk '/^0/{print $2}' | \
  xargs -n 1 tmux kill-session -t
```

This solution is more robust than the one proposed by abieler because it mathces all detached sessions by ID, not matter what their name is (the solution by abieler would skip a detached session called *attached*).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to kill all detached sessions

```
tmux list-sessions | grep -v attached | cut -d: -f1 |  xargs -t -n1 tmux kill-session -t
```

With comments/explanation:

```
tmux list-sessions   | # list all tmux sessions
  grep -v attached   | # grep for all lines that do NOT contain the pattern "attached"
  cut -d: -f1        | # cut with the separator ":" and select field 1 (the session name)
  xargs -t -n1       ` # -t echoes the command, -n1 limits xargs to 1 argument ` \
  tmux kill-session -t # kill session with target -t passed from xargs
```

Comment: Can you put some description of what you're actually doing here?

Also, this will kill _all_ attached sessions, you should note this.

Comment: @djsmiley2k All detached sessions you mean (`-v` flag).

Answer (score 2):

You can kill a specific tnux session by typing:

```
tmux kill-session -t [session]
```

Just replace `[session]` with the session you want to kill.

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to kill all detached sessions

`tmux ls | awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/.$//'| xargs -t -n1 tmux kill-session -t`